# How to calculate wall sizes with square meters and wall ratio

Tags: calculus

Let's say i got the following information for a square room:

Square meters ≈ 21m2
wall ratio of 1 to 1,14 (so we could have a room of 3x3,46 or 2,5x2,85)

How could i mathematically determine the wall lengths of my room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area $S = xy$, where $x$ and $y$ are for sides length. As $x = 1.14y$, we can write $S = 1.14y^2 = 21$, so $y^2 = 18.42 \Rightarrow y = 4.29$ sq.m. and $x = 1.14y = 4.89$ sq.m.

Comment: That's faboulous. Thanks alot :)